# Jquery Mobile Design - Worklight

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I am working on a sample project of worklight where I am using the login module. So I am triggering the login module page from the `wlCommonInit`

```
function wlCommonInit(){

    WL.Client.login("AuthRealm", {onSuccess: winFunction, onFailure: failureFunction}); 


}
```

Included

```
window.$ = WLJQ;
window.jQuery = WLJQ;
```

for Jquery Mobile designing. But still the Jquery Mobile design is working as it shows a normal text box. Here`s my complete html code

```
        <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>LatestKen</title>
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.2.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/LatestKen.css">
    <script>
    window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;
</script>
    <script src="jqueryMobile/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.2.js"></script>
    <script
        src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">

    </script>
    </head>
    <body  id="content" style="display: none;">

        <div data-role="page" id="page2" style="display: none">
            <div data-role="header" id="header0" data-position="fixed">
                <h3>Select the Facility</h3>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content" name="contentConfirmation">



                <input type="button" value="Logout"
                    onclick="WL.Client.logout('AuthRealm', {onSuccess:WL.Client.reloadApp})" />
    <div id="response"></div>

                <div id="facility1"></div>
                <br>
                <div id="facility2"></div>

                <br>
                <div id="facility3"></div>
                <br>
                <div id="facility4"></div>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" id="footer">
                <h3 align="center">Footer</h3>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="page3" style="display: none">

            <div data-role=header>

                <h1>Home</h1>

            </div>

            <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">
                <p>hello</p>
                <ul data-role="listview" id="listview" data-inset="true"
                    data-filter="true">
                    <li data-role="list-divider" id="divider">Available Devices</li>

                </ul>


            </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" id="footer">
            <h3>Footer</h3>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="AuthDiv" style="display: none">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h2>Login</h2>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">

                <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="text">Username:</label><input type="text" name="text"
                        id="AuthUsername">
                </div>

                <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="fieldcontain0">
                    <label for="text0">Password:</label><input type="text" name="text0"
                        id="AuthPassword">

                </div>

                <div class="ui-grid-a">
                    <div class="ui-block-a">
                        <input type="button" id="AuthCancelButton" value="cancel">
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">

                        <input type="button" data-role="button" id="AuthSubmitButton"
                            value="submit">

                    </div>

                    <div id="ResponseDiv"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
        <script src="js/LatestKen.js"></script>
        <script src="js/authChallengeHandler.js"></script>
        <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
        <script src="js/map.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Whenever user logs in, I am showing the `#Page2`, From there I am binding a click event, that runs a procedure. On success of it I am changing it to Page 3 like this.

```
function loadSQLQuerySuccess(result) {
    WL.Logger.debug("Retrieve success" +  JSON.stringify(result));
    $("#page2").hide();
    $("#page3").show();
    displayFeeds(result.invocationResult.resultSet);
}
```

`displayFeeds` function takes care of styling the listview. But that too not supporting jquery mobile designing. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you inject items into page3 before or after leaving page2?

Comment: I am binding a click event on a div #facility1, On clicking it I am calling a procedure. Onsuccess (Function) of that procedure, I am injecting the data to Page3.

Comment: And then you navigate to page3? the listview isn't styled?

Comment: Pls check the edited question, Omar.

Comment: instead of `.hide()` and `.show()`, just add this `$.mobile.changePage('#page3');` although I'm not sure whether Worklight tolerate it. This is the right way of navigating between pages on JQM.

Comment: But the design should support for the first page, no? Wlclient() function triggeres the first page and the JQM design is not supporting it too.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but a few notes: * You don't mention what version of Worklight you are using.  * jquery.mobile-1.1.2 - is there a reason that you aren't using 1.2 or 1.3?.  I'm not sure that it is compatible with the jQuery bundled in Worklight.  You might try updating JQM * Why are you setting display:none on your pages?  JQM should manage that.  * $.mobile.changepage() works great with Worklight, and as Omar noted, you should be using that.  * I suspect that a screenshot might help explain what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I think the comments are correct. The styling isn't occurring on your list because you are not showing your list the 'jquery way'. Which would be by calling $.mobile.changepage() (as mentioned in the comments).

Whenever I do a jquery mobile project and I dynamically update a listview, I always have to call the following function in order to have the jquery mobile styling applied:

```
$('#list_view_id').listview('refresh');
```

You should try calling this for your listview in the callback function for your page change.